# Event listener for changing attribute in a div through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My div looks like the following:

```
<div id="modal"
     style="position: fixed;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       opacity: 0.4;
       background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
       display: block;
       z-index: 99;">
</div>
```

I want something to happen when my div changes to (note: display block has changed to none):

```
<div id="modal"
     style="position: fixed;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       opacity: 0.4;
       background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
       display: none;
       z-index: 99;">
</div>
```

I was thinking about a EventListener, does anybody have any idea how to get this working?

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: I have no working code, I puzzled with the div but i ain't got it working, so I was wondering if there is anybody with an idea about where i should be looking for.

Comment: How is the css of the div going to change? through some script?

Comment: Yes. It's a clickable table with records, and when a record is doubleclicked it changes the div.

Comment: Then why dont you "do your task" in that event only. Call a function when record is clicked

Comment: Wouldn't you listen for a doubleclick if a doubleclick is needed to change said div?

Comment: @anu and zer00ne are right. The event you need to listen for is the record double-click. Since you know that *is* the event that changes the div styles, it can also serve as the event to listen for.

Comment: Yes i thought the same, but it's complex code and i've been trying alot to get that working, but i didn't manage to fix it on that way yet. But I will try some more.

Comment: Well, share some relevant  markup and script code. Maybe people here can help then.

Comment: there are lots of third party editable table javascript libraries -- why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @MarkieDoe - see my answer below for the simplest way I can think of to implement this kind of setup.

Comment: And what if i use like a callback?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Something like

```
var target = document.getElementById('modal');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
      ...
    }
  });    
});
```

Comment: This is super useful information, however it could be more complete. Look at [this SO post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen out for the double click and then execute:

- one function to change the CSS; and
- another function for whatever is supposed to happen after the CSS
  changes

**Example:**

```
var records = document.getElementsByClassName('record');

function changeCSS() {

    [... CODE HERE...]

}

function doSomethingElse() {

    [... CODE HERE...]

}

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    record.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){changeCSS(); doSomethingElse();}, false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script in your code. You have to use set interval or timeout function to display div as a none.

Below I have used setTimeout() function, so after 2 seconds 'display : none' style get applied to the div.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){           
           setTimeout(function () {
               $('#modal').css('display','none');
            }, 2000);

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is already a double click event happening when the user clicks the table, you can listen to that event with the  `.dblclick(function()`

For example:

Script:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modal").dblclick(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('newClass');
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.newClass
{
     width:100%,
     height:100%,
     background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
     ...
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle between the display show and hide, then uncomment the commented tags. Also make "$('div#modal').on('click', function() {" and "$('div#modal').hide();" as comment

```js
   $('div#modal').show();
    // $('button').on('click',function(){
   $('div#modal').on('click', function() {
     //$(this).css("display","none");
     //event.stopPropagation();
     //$('div#modal').toggle();
     $('div#modal').hide();
   })
```

```html
<div id="modal" style="position: fixed;
           left: 0px;
           /*top: 50px;*/
           top:0px;
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           opacity: 0.4;
           background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
           z-index: 99;">
</div>
<br>
<!--<button>Click</button>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Good Luck!!!