# JavaScript: Listen for attribute change?

Tags: javascript, attributes, event-handling, custom-events

Is it possible in JavaScript to listen for a change of attribute value? For example:

```
var element=document.querySelector('…');
element.addEventListener( ? ,doit,false);

element.setAttribute('something','whatever');

function doit() {

}
```

I would like to respond to any change in the `something` attribute.

I have read up on the `MutationObserver` object, as well as alternatives to that (including the one which uses animation events). As far as I can tell, they are about changes to the actual DOM. I’m more interested in attribute changes to a particular DOM element, so I don’t think that’s it. Certainly in my experimenting it doesn’t seem to work.

I would like to do this *without* jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: `MutationObserver` works for that. Just configure it to listen to attribute changes. Set it to observe only the element you’re interested in.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You need [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), Here in snippet I have used `setTimeout` to simulate modifying attribute

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#test');
setTimeout(function() {
  element.setAttribute('data-text', 'whatever');
}, 5000)

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log("attributes changed");

      // Example of accessing the element for which 
      // event was triggered
      mutation.target.textContent = "Attribute of the element changed";
    }
    
    console.log(mutation.target);
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

```html
<div id="test">Dummy Text</div>
```

Additionally, [mutation.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/target) property gives the reference to  mutated/changed node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the sample. Once I have streamlined this, I think it will be good technique for making more complex changes to elements by simply changing and attribute. It makes an easier API. Would you be aware of a reasonable polyfill for primitive browsers?

Comment: @Manngo, For primitive browsers you can use [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and also see https://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript

Comment: I see that it is currently supported back to IE9, and still supported in modern browsers. Thanks again.

Comment: kinda useless when we have no access to the element in the observer

Comment: `mutation.target` is the element within the observer mutations

Answer (score 12):

This question is already answered, but I'd like to share my experiences, because the mutation observer did not bring me the insights in needed.

**Note** This is some kind of hacky solution, but for (at least) debugging purposes quite good.

You can override the `setAttribute` function of a particalar element. This way you can also print the callstack, and get an insight of "who" changed the attribute value:

```
// select the target element
const target = document.querySelector("#element");
// store the original setAttribute reference
const setAttribute = target.setAttribute;
// override setAttribte
target.setAttribute = (key: string, value: string) => {
  console.trace("--trace");
  // use call, to set the context and prevent illegal invocation errors
  setAttribute.call(target, key, value); 
};
```

Comment: A clever hack. Note that if `setAttributeNS()` is called this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use pub/sub (took this from someone who, no doubt, rightfully stole it from someone else):

```
        PubSub: function () {

        //var topics = {};
        //var hOP = topics.hasOwnProperty;
        var hasProp = Me.Subscriptions.hasOwnProperty;

        return {
            Subscribe: function (topic, listener) {
                // Create the topic's object if not yet created
                if (!hasProp.call(Me.Subscriptions, topic)) Me.Subscriptions[topic] = [];

                // Add the listener to queue
                var index = Me.Subscriptions[topic].push(listener) - 1;

                // Provide handle back for removal of topic
                return {
                    remove: function () {
                        delete Me.Subscriptions[topic][index];
                    }
                };
            },
            Publish: function (topic, info) {
                // If the topic doesn't exist, or there's no listeners in queue, just leave
                if (!hasProp.call(Me.Subscriptions, topic)) return;

                // Cycle through topics queue, fire!
                Me.Subscriptions[topic].forEach(function (item) {
                    item(info != undefined ? info : {});
                });
            }
        };
    },
```

Usage:

Publish:

```
PubSub.Subscriber().Publish('AppLoaded', true);
```

Subscribe:

```
PubSub.Subscriber().Subscribe('AppLoaded', function (result) {

    //I can now do things I'll tell my friends I did anyway
            
});
```