# How do I execute an action when an attribute value changes using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` that contains the attribute `aria-hidden`. I would like to set up a listener or execute an action each time the attribute value dynamically changes.

**My div is**

```
<div class="slide2" aria-hidden="*"></div>
```

The value for "aria-hidden" could either be true or false.

**My code is:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".slide2").bind('change', function(event) {
     if ( $('.slide2').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false' ) {
        alert('do something');
     }
   });
});
```

I have read examples using `MutationObserver` but that examples I've seen display an action being executed when ANY element attribute changes. I would like to see an example showing that when a specific div (`<div class="slide2"></div>`) changes an action is executed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Listen for attribute change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change)

Comment: @Roman The examples are close and use the MutationObserver but the examples are not similar to mine. One example shows me how to set my attribute and listen to it. I would like an example of that shows if my attribute changes to a specific value (true or false) not just change

Comment: @Mariton you just have do do an additional check - made a litle code snipet for you.. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Inside of the `observer` you have to check the `attribute` you want to change. I did it with pure javascript (`mutation.target.getAttribute('aria-hidden')`).
With the `attributeFilter` you can choose specific attributes to observe. In your case `aria-hidden`.

### The Important Part

```
var slideObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
      // here you can play with it now :)
      if (mutation.target.getAttribute('aria-hidden') == "true") {
        console.log('ok. aria-hidden is true') 
      } else {
        console.log(':s aria-hidden is false') 
      }      
    }
  });
});
```

### Example

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver

var slide = document.querySelector('.slide2')

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', toggleAriaHiddenRole)

var slideObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
      
      // here you can play with it now :)
      if (mutation.target.getAttribute('aria-hidden') == "true") {
        console.log('ok. aria-hidden is true') 
      } else {
        console.log(':s aria-hidden is false') 
      }      
    }
  });
});

slideObserver.observe(slide, {
  attributes: true, //configure it to listen to attribute changes
  attributeFilter: ['aria-hidden'] // filter your attributes
});

function changeAriaHiddenRole(element, boolean) {
  element.setAttribute('aria-hidden', boolean)
}

function toggleAriaHiddenRole(boolean) {
  if (slide.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === "true") {
    changeAriaHiddenRole(slide, false)
  } else {
    changeAriaHiddenRole(slide, true)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide2" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<button id="btn">toggle aria-hidden</button>
```

Comment: seems like this should work. It's a great answer but its not working for me

Comment: explain me why. may be we can find a solution together

Comment: not sure but I copied your code and looked in the console and did not see a message of 'ok. aria-hidden is true' or 'ok. aria-hidden is false' . My did specifically is `<div class="slide2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01"></div>`

Comment: i add 'aria-role' to the `attributeFilter` so you observe only the 'aria-role'

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference I did notice that when the the the div `<div class="slide2">` becomes active a class of active is added to the div for example `<div class="slide2 active">` . Maybe I should do something when active is added to the div. Not sure if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after I put the js code at the bottom of the file. The possible error occurs should be:

> parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

That is because the listener was executed before the DOM was read, so obviously, it has to be loaded before you call `observe(node, config);`

here is one suggestion:

```
<body>
<div class="slide2" aria-hidden="*"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".slide2").bind('change', function(event) {
     if ( $('.slide2').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false' ) {
        alert('do something');
     }
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```