# Listen for attribute change in link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using s3 library that directly uploads content from browser and returns the content inside a link tag. Now i want to display the url in link as an image. The current code i have working so far

```
var icon = document.getElementById("selectLogo");

icon.addEventListener("click",(evt)=> {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("file-input")[0];
    element.click();
});

var icon_link = document.getElementsByClassName("file-link")[0];

icon_link.addEventListener("onchange",(evt)=> {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(icon_link);
});
```

where `icon` my `img` tag which triggers a click on `upload` button. The problem i am facing is with `icon_link` which is an `link tag`. What i want is to listen for `href` attribute change and update image accordingly . How can that be possible all using vanilla js and no external dependencies ?

Comment: My bad.. let me update the code :)

Comment: the issue was not that. i accedentally changed cases while copying code. the upload event is triggering .

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir there. sorry about that :)

Comment: `change` event won't be fired by the change in `href` attribute.

Comment: How does the element get its `href` changed? Who change it?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir got it via mutation change :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a mutation observer to watch for attribute changes on a DOM node. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425087/459966

Comment: You should close as dupe. This is not an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough rep points. Feel free to though.