# How to observe adding class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In my **div** I want to **observe** his class, so when this class `passed` is added to my div, I execute some js function.

Initial div : `<div id="1" class="allow"></div>`

after adding a new class :  `<div id="1" class="allow passed"></div>`

my function to execute :

```
function fill() {
        jQuery('#check').show();
        jQuery('#check-val').hide();
    }
```

Comment: Why not call fill() from the method that adds the passed class?

Comment: good question but I do not have access @Taplar

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed

Comment: @Austin Truex not class changed but added, I saw that question before post it :)

Comment: Use Austin's suggestion, then check it's the class you want with .hasClass()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Listen for attribute change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a mutation observer on that div to detect when a class is added. Notice the usage of mutation observers..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
            if ($(mutation.target).hasClass('passed')){
                    alert("passed class was added");
                    fill();
           }
         }
     });
  });

observer.observe(document.getElementById('1'), {
  attributes: true
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e37am2hq/

Comment: It is possible to check exactly this added class `passed`

Comment: I modified my answer, and the jsfiddle. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Use jQuery hasClass function. Above function may fail if passed is not at last.

Comment: Just approved your edit @DnyaneshwarSupe. `hasClass()` is cleaner. and yeah, `.passed` would have needed to be the last class in the list.

Comment: @Austin Truex, sorry but no, in your `setTimeout(function() {
$("#1").addClass('passed');
}, 3000)` if I replace ``addClass('passed');` to `addClass('no-passed');` it still detecte it

Comment: How did you run it? The `hasClass()` just checks to see if that element has the class passed.. if the class is already there, it will return true. You could also use my original method which is posted in the jsfiddle, however that method requires that `.passed` is the last class in the class list