# Change (content) text in div element once the class changes on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just need small jquery help. So we would like to change the value of text on the left element .. So the number **(1)** should be changed to number **(2)** once user scroll to 2nd slide.

The body class changes to once you scroll:
**fp-viewing-1**

Here video of the website:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10OcUoyvh1Xr3pWmxqzdR67wI8IlkPsNF/view?usp=sharing

Here is what I tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('body').attr("class") == "fp-viewing-1") {
         $('#count').addClass('something');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Once the class is added I was thinking to change the html value with css..

```
 content: "";
```

Comment: What you want is an observer on the `class` attribute. That's all about mutation observers...

See (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425087/3748178 (2) https://devdocs.io/dom/mutationobserver - watch out for browser support and (3) https://devdocs.io/dom/element/classlist

Comment: What library are you using for the scrolling? I would expect it to raise an event you can listen for when a slide changes. Listening for DOM changes would be a rather hacky workaround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Listen for attribute change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// you can use two Intervals to detect as there is no event for class change in Jquery  
$(document).ready(function () {
        startProcess();
    });
    function startProcess() {
        var checkExist1 = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('body').hasClass("fp-viewing-1")) {
                clearInterval(checkExist1);
                alert("1 detected")
                var checkExist0 = setInterval(function () {
                    if ($('body').hasClass("fp-viewing-0")) {
                        clearInterval(checkExist0);
                        startProcess();
                        alert("0 detected")
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of Intervals, We Could Use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe). Which Is a more suitable, reliable & efficient way.