# Firing custom event on iframe src change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire conversion event if the iframe src changes as follows:

```
var src = document.getElementById("iframeID").src; // get the src
var url = "https://example.com/?123"

if(src.indexOf(url) !=-1){ //this will return -1 if false

document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = "<script>gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xyz/xyz'});<\/script>";

}else{
    alert("wrong url");
}
```

and then

`<div id="myid"></div>`

All good and the script gets added to the div tag but the conversion is not firing the conversion in tag assistant.

I have also initially tried to fire the code without script like this:

```
var src = document.getElementById("iframeID").src; // get the src
var url = "https://example.com/?123"

if(src.indexOf(url) !=-1){ //this will return -1 if false

gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xyz/xyz'});

}else{
    alert("wrong url");
}
```

But I would get gtag is not defined

What am i missing?

Comment: Just run the command, you're already inside a script!

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Can you please post code example?

Comment: Just run `gtag(.....) ;` instead of trying to insert it into a new `<script >` tag

Comment: I think i have tried that initialy and got "gtag is not defined". Maybe did not run it correctly. Can you please add your code suggestion here?

Comment: Check @AlonEitan i have added the code as you suggested which i have tried first thing.

Answer (score 0):

According [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change), in order to listen to attribute changes, you would need a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID");
iframe.setAttribute('data-oldsrc', iframe.getAttribute('src'));
var url = "https://example.com/?123"

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
            var src = iframe.src; // get the src
            if(iframe.getAttribute('data-oldsrc')){ // If the mutation is in 'src'
                if(src.indexOf(url) !=-1){ // If the src contains the url
                    // Trigger event
                    gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xyz/xyz'});

                }else{
                    alert("wrong url");
                }
            }
            
        }
    })
});

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

Don't forget to [add gatg javascript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs#install_the_global_site_tag) to your page (you are probably trying to [route data to groups and properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#groups-and-properties)):

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
```