# Update info if scrollbar is visible in React with usaga of simplebar-react

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I use `simplebar-react` and I wanted to get the information when the scrollbar is visible.
I created a custom hook to catch this info

```
export const useIsScrollbarVisible = () => {
  const [isScrollbarVisible, setIsScrollbarVisible] = useState(false);
  
  const scrollbarRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setIsScrollbarVisible(!scrollbarRef?.current?.hidden || false);
  }, [])

  return {
    scrollbarRef,
    isScrollbarVisible
  }
}
```

and the usage

```
  const { isScrollbarVisible, scrollbarRef } = useIsScrollbarVisible();

      <Scrollbar scrollableNodeProps={{ ref: scrollbarRef }}>
        <Box {...(isScrollbarVisible && { pr: 3 })}>
          {...}
        </Box>
     </Scrollbar>
```

but it doesnt update the info if scrollbar is visible or not.

Comment: only two things I think you can try, as you're trying to bring the DOM into the react render cycle which doesn't work the way you're attempting. You could try removing the dependency array from your useLayoutEffect, as an empty array means it will only run once - this will lead to performance issues though (add a console log in there to see what I mean). Alternatively in the useLayoutEffect you can add a mutation observer to watch for attribute changes see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be related to the way you are checking if the scrollbar is visible. Instead of relying on scrollbarRef?.current?.hidden, you can use the scrollHeight and clientHeight properties to determine if the scrollbar is visible. Here's an updated version of your custom hook:

```
import { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export const useIsScrollbarVisible = () => {
const [isScrollbarVisible, setIsScrollbarVisible] = useState(false);
const scrollbarRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const checkScrollbarVisibility = () => {
    const scrollbarNode = scrollbarRef?.current;
    if (scrollbarNode) {
     setIsScrollbarVisible(scrollbarNode.scrollHeight > 
      scrollbarNode.clientHeight);
    }
 };

checkScrollbarVisibility(); // Check on mount

// Update when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScrollbarVisibility);

// Clean up the event listener
  return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('resize', checkScrollbarVisibility);
  };
}, []);

return {
   scrollbarRef,
   isScrollbarVisible,
};
};
```

With this approach, the hook will check the scrollbar visibility on mount and also listen for window resize events to update the visibility status. Make sure to test this modification in your specific setup to ensure it meets your requirements.

Comment: but the scrollbar is not for all window, but in some component, so this dont help